# PSNR of two images of different size in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, interpolation

I performed bicubic interpolation on a 256*256 image(img)

```
 dest = interp2(img,'bicubic')
```

and  i got a 511 * 511 image.I want to compute PSNR of a 512 * 512 image(original) and the 'dest' image as follows

```
original = double(original);
dest = double(dest);
[M N] = size(original);
error = original - dest;
MSE = sum(sum(error .* error)) / (M * N);

if(MSE > 0)
PSNR = 10*log(255*255/MSE) / log(10);
disp(['PSNR = ', num2str(PSNR)])
else
PSNR = 99;
disp(['PSNR = ', num2str(PSNR)])
end
```

But I'm getting error due to unmatched matrix dimensions.How to avoid this error.Is it possible to calculate PSNR of images with different size?Please help

Comment: Are you sure you have to interpolate then calculate PSNR? maybe you could add a noise to image and then calculate PSNR. According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio), PSNR is calculated for noisy and noise free images not interpolated ones.

Comment: @Kamtal - Shrinking an image then resizing it could be considered a noisy signal.  There are interpolation artifacts when increasing the size of the image.  This is actually a common thing to do when comparing different image interpolation algorithms where you purposely shrink and resize the image and see how close the reconstruction is with the original.  Some algorithms have very poor reconstruction quality while some are better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is decrease the size of the image by a factor of 2, then interpolate back so that you get the original image size back.  You want to check the quality of this reconstruction by calculating the PSNR between them.

However, I would highly advise against resizing an image using `interp2`.  `interp2` is good for general 2D signals.  If you want to resize images, use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) instead.  It is specifically designed for resizing images, and handles cases such as trying to interpolate for pixels out of bounds and other edges cases that would be a headache to work with in `interp2`.

With `imresize`, you can specify exactly what dimensions you want.  In this case, you would either increase your size by a factor of 2, or you can specify 512 x 512 directly.  That way, you won't get your 511 x 511 inconsistent image size error, and are able to compute the PSNR normally as both images are the same size.

Assuming that `dest` is the shrunken image that is 256 x 256, you should do something like this:

```
%// Cast for precision
original = double(original);
dest = double(dest);

%// Increase size of image
dest_resized = imresize(dest, [512 512], 'bicubic');

%// Compute your stuff
[M N] = size(original);
err = original - dest_resized;
MSE = sum(sum(err .* err)) / (M * N);
PSNR = 10*log(255*255/MSE) / log(10);
```

**Minor Note:**  Your PSNR isn't quite right.  You don't need the `log(10)` division there.  Consult the PSNR definition for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio

---

However, if you're dead set on using `interp2`, if you want to get the original size back, you need to define a grid of co-ordinates that is 0.5 in steps based on the original image size for `interp2`.  This way you will get a 512 x 512 image as a result.  However, there may be a case where you will try and interpolate values that are not defined in the grid.  As such, you need to replace any values that are invalid with an imputed value... say `0`.

As such, you need to do this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(dest,2), 1:size(dest,1));
[X2,Y2] = meshgrid(0.5:0.5:size(dest,2), 0.5:0.5:size(dest,1));
dest = double(dest);
dest_resized = interp2(X, Y, dest, X2, Y2, 'bicubic');
dest_resized(isnan(dest_resized)) = 0;
```